# Добавить ссылку в список option с использованием PHP!

Tags: php, html, list, ссылки

Нужно вывести форму со списком и значениями: «Google», «Instagram», «Apple». Добавьте кнопку «Перейти на сайт».
В зависимости от того, что выберет пользователь, необходимо сделать редирект на https://google.ru, https://instagram.com или на https://apple.ru
Пробовал много раз но никак не получалось выводит только ошибку.
И САМОЕ ГЛАВНОЕ!!! тут не нужно использовать js только на PHP!

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: нужно добавить ссылки в значения - "option", которые находятся в списке - "select", чтобы через значения переходить по ссылкам в определенные сайт.

Comment: [Как задать хороший вопрос?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score -1):

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['test'])) {
if($_POST['test'] == 'instagramm') {exit(header('Location: https://instagramm.com'));}
elseif($_POST['test'] == 'google') {exit(header('Location: https://google.com'));}
elseif($_POST['test'] == 'apple') {exit(header('Location: https://apple.com'));}
else {exit('ошибка');}
}
?>

<form method="post" action="<?=$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']?>">
<select name="test">
<option value="instagramm">instagramm</option>
<option value="google">google</option>
<option value="apple">apple</option>
</select>
```

Comment: минусователь, проясни что не так, по сути вопроса

Comment: Мне кажется странно задавать вопрос "в воздух", т.к. чел ткнул минус и ушёл, а не сидит и ждёт, когда же тут отвечающий возмущаться будет